# Can I determine the saturation value of \$I_{B}\$ from the intersection of the load line with the output I-V curves?

Tags: transistors

[image]
To know the values of \$I_{B},V_{CE}\$ and \$I_C\$
In the saturation region, all I have to do is look at the point A in the above figure, right? But that can't be the case since \$I_B\$
there is 1/100 times \$I_C\$, assuming β=100. However, the minimum \$I_B\$ needed for saturation, typically, is only \$\frac{1}{20}I_C\$ with a forced \$\beta\$ of 20. So, what am I missing here?

*The figure in the question is adopted from this video*
https://youtu.be/QMI30-GxG5k?t=420

Comment: I believe you've been made aware of the different definitions used for "saturation" in previous questions. Why persist using this one?

Comment: Sorry Tim, but I don't get what you mean.

Comment: You're basically asking "why doesn't [definition 2] mean [definition 1]?" The figure defines saturation as the labeled region, period; the other definitions (B-C forward bias, forced hFE) are just that: *other definitions*. Does that make sense?

Comment: What do the coordinates of the point A in the figure tell me?

Comment: Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/311243/bjt-base-current-calculation/311306#311306

Comment: Or here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/276146/a-question-about-vce-of-an-npn-bjt-in-saturation-region/276266#276266

Comment: @Jack [This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqWdg.png) shows you clearly delineated modes. Do you notice that the \$\beta\$ can still be 100 while also in shallow saturation (CB junction voltage of NPN nearer to 0 V)? As the saturation deepens (more to the left) the \$\beta\$ takes a deep dive. But only as the CB junction nears to a `diode drop` magnitude. That's all there is to it.

Comment: With assumption of beta=20 you are forcing 5 times higher Ib. Another words, you forgot about inversion: lower Beta assumption -> higher Ib -> deeper saturation.

Comment: @Jack I think you are like a character in [the blind men and an elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant) story. You read one description from a limited perspective, then another from a different perspective also limited in scope, and so on. You then find yourself here, today, wondering who's been lying to you. Just as in the fable. I think it is high time for you to face the actual creature itself: [the Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation). Let loose of old ideas, embrace this one, and then understand diodes and BJTs well.

Comment: @periblepsis thanks

Comment: You make assumptions AND wonder why an arbitrary graph does not agree with your assumptions.  Calculate β from graph and your issue is moot.