Role of the load resistors in an astable multivibrator
I am currently trying to wrap my head around astable multivibrators. I want to design a circuit that oscilates at about 1 kHz. The formula I am using to determine the values for the base resistors (I am building a symetric circuit; r1=r2 and c1=c2) and caps is frequency = (2*ln(2)*r*c)^-1.
I chose a 10 nF cap and a 68 kΩ resistor, which isn't quite right for 1 kHz, but since I am doing this for learning purposes it doesn't really matter. When I built this circuit, the waveform looked awful.
I simulated it and found out that when the resistance of the load resistors, which I thought only regulated the current in order to not burn out the transistor or LED, is under 600 Ω, for example 240 Ω, the waveform is not even close to square.
When I choose a resistor greater than 600 Ω, for example 1 kΩ, the waveform is like I expect. Can anyone explain to me why that is? In the following images you can see the simulation of the circuit with a 240 Ω load resistor and the circuit with a 1 kΩ load resistor.
The blue graph shows the voltage of the output and the green graph shows the voltage of a cap.



What is the current gain of a transistor used in simulation? With the low-value resistors at the collectors compared to the RB resistors. The transistors are not fully saturated. If in the simulation the β value is 100 then RC_min = RB/100 = 720Ω.
In real circuits RC_min = RC/(10...50)

That makes sense, the hfe of the simulation was indeed 100, in the real circuit i used a 2n2222. I want to clarify to make sure i understand: the transistor was, in the 240 ohm circuit, not saturated, because the possible current from the collector to the emitter would be about 21 mA. The current reaching the base of the transistor that is on would be about 0.07 mA, which, when multiplied with the hfe of lets say 100, is 7 mA, which is smaller than the current that wants to flow from the collector to the emitter. Correct? Thank you for your very helpfull answer!

Yes, you got it right.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355899/how-is-possible-that-with-same-ibase-there-is-more-than-one-vce/355955#355955  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/311243/bjt-base-current-calculation/311306#311306

Thank you very much, this was very helpful!

I'm glad that I could help.

If you want to get the design working comfortably with 240 Ω in the collector, consider using Darlington configured transistors made from two 2N2222 BJTs: -

There are of course better ways to design a simple square wave oscillator using a Schmitt trigger.

Thank you, that is a cool solution! The circuits only purpose was to be educational for me, so it didnt need to be particularly good. I ended up using bigger capacitors, which allowed me to use smaller value base resistors, which solved the saturation issue G36 mentioned in theire answer.
